# PHP renumber array but keep sequence

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array(13,4,7,1,16);
```

I want to recount the array, but I want to keep the sequence, like this:

```
array(4,2,3,1,5);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What? What you want to do? This is completely unclear...

Comment: recount? asort()? `$myArray = array(13,4,7,1,16); assort($myArray); var_dump(array_keys($myArray));`

Comment: Does not work @MarkBaker

Comment: Don't simply say "does not work"...... explain what it is that you actually want. Your explanation of what you want is completely unclear: I made a simple guess, so it may well be wrong, but without being able to understand what it is you want, then all we can do is guess.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `recount`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get the index of the array with reference to the sorted values

Try this

```
 $numbers = array(13,4,7,1,16);
$numberscopy = $numbers;
sort($numberscopy);
$final = array();
//echo array_search(13, $numbers);
for($a=0 ; $a<count($numberscopy );$a++){

$final[] = array_search($numberscopy[$a], $numbers) + 1;
}
var_dump($final);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to sort the array, keeping the keys in the same order as the values, the PHP `asort()` function does that.

If you want to keep the original array but get the keys in sort order, then you can use something like:

```
$arr = array(13,4,7,1,16);
asort($arr);
$keys = array_keys($arr);
```

Then $keys has the keys from the original array sorted in the order of the original values, e.g. $keys = array(4,2,3,1,5);

Comment: I don't want to sort the array, I want to keep the sequence, but I want to recount it, see my example

Comment: Edited original answer.